# How to get s3 file url with user Id using django rest frame work?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

My s3 file URL after upload image - "https://demo-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/pics/fever.jpg"
Required URL is - "https://demo-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/pics/@userId/fever.jpg"

```
Models.py

    class MedicalRecord(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date_time = models.DateTimeField()
        user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        record_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='pic')
    
    Serializer.py
    
    class MedicalRecordModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = MedicalRecord
            fields = '__all__'
    Views.py
    
    class MedicalRecordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = MedicalRecordModelSerializer
        queryset = MedicalRecord.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `upload_to` function.

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'pic/%s/%s' % (instance.user, filename)

class MedicalRecord(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    record_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
```